# Does SSRS Cache report generate a new cache automatically after expiration?

Tags: caching, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When you cache a report in SSRS 2008 and set it to expire after a number of minutes, for example 30 minutes, Does the report refresh after it expires and generate a new cached report automatically or it refreshes only when the report is requested or run?

For example, if I run the report at 10:00AM, it will expire at 10:30AM, then when someone else runs the report at 11:15AM, Will there have been a new Cached report or it will be processed as new(in other words, it is not based on a Cached report)?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after reading some more documentation, I'd found out that there is an option to do a cache refresh plan on a schedule.  Won't these two options be the same or very identical:
Option1 - I cache a report and set it to expire after 30 minutes and also set it to refresh every 30 minutes
Option2 - I set the report to do snapshots every 30 minutes
I think these will output the same or very identical results, except that I do not have the option to do a report history by using the cache option, is this correct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the default behavior is that an expired cache is not refreshed until the report is accessed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx

However, a cache refresh plan can be used to periodically refresh the cache according to a schedule.

This is less useful for parameterized reports where the parameters are changed frequently.

Edit: See here for more info.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d7e8c6c8-2331-476f-b03e-f558458fa283/snapshots-vs-cached-instances?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after reading some more documentation, I'd found out that there is an option to do a cache refresh plan on a schedule.  Won't these two options be the same or very identical:
Option1 - I cache a report and set it to expire after 30 minutes and also set it to refresh every 30 minutes
Option2 - I set the report to do snapshots every 30 minutes
I think these will output the same or very identical results, except that I do not have the option to do a report history by using the cache option, is this correct?

Thanks!!

Comment: Great question.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d7e8c6c8-2331-476f-b03e-f558458fa283/snapshots-vs-cached-instances?forum=sqlreportingservices